# Seifert Matrix for a Knot's Mirror Image

Tags: knot-theory

Question: What is the relation between the Seifert matrix of a knot, $V$, found using some given Seifert surface, $S$, and the Seifert matrix for its mirror image, $V'$, found using the mirror image of the given Seifert surface, $S'$?

The mirror image can be formed by switching every crossing of the Seifert matrix (i.e. every under-crossing in $S$ becomes an over-crossing in $S'$ and vice versa). When forming the mirror image, the orientation is reversed as well.

My thoughts so far:
I am not sure what happens to a general entry $V_{i,j}$ when we form the mirror image. My initial thought is that $V_{i,j}=-V'_{j,i}$. My reason for believing this comes from the Seifert matrix for the trefoil and its mirror image.

I have calculated the Seifert matrix for the trefoil: $$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$ as well as the Seifert matrix for the mirror image of the trefoil: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you are reversing the orientation of the Seifert surface when taking the mirror image.  The orientation of the Seifert surface induces the orientation of the knot, so you are computing the Seifert matrix of the mirror image of the knot with reversed orientation.  Separately, the Seifert matrix of the mirror image of the knot is $-V$ and the Seifert matrix for the knot with reversed orientation is $V^T$.  (Proposition 6.12 of Lickorish.)

Briefly:

- When doing a mirror image, all the crossings flip, and $\operatorname{lk}(f_i^{-},f_j)$ becomes negative what it was, where $f_i^{-}$ is the push-off of $f_i$ behind the Seifert surface.
- When reversing orientation, the push-off is backwards from what it was, and is $\operatorname{lk}(f_i^{+},f_j)$ with respect to the original orientation, which is equivalently $\operatorname{lk}(f_i,f_j^{-})$.  Thus the Seifert matrix is transposed.

Comment: Yes I am reversing the orientation. I will edit the question. Sorry that was left out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kyle Miller I apologize for commenting on an old answer, but I think to obtain a Seifert surface whose orientation is compatible with the mirror of the knot, one needs to reverse the orientation of the Seifert surface after reflecting it. (For instance, consider reflecting a disk which bounds a circle in the $xy$-plane about the $xy$-plane.) So I think, despite what is written in Lickorish, the Seifert matrix of the mirror should be $-V^T$, not $-V$. Is this correct?

Comment: @KyleMiller Thank you for responding! When I work with the example of a left/right trefoil knot, I seem to get $-V^T$ instead of $-V$. Let $K$ be the original knot with Seifert surface $F$, and $\phi\colon S^3\to S^3$ a reflection. Give $\phi F$ an orientation which is compatible with $\phi K$ (the reverse of the orientation induced by $\Phi$ from $F$.) If $[f_i]\in H_1(F)$ form a basis, the $(i,j)$th entry of the Seifert matrix for $\phi(K)$ should be (I think) $$\mathrm{lk}((\phi f_i)^-, \phi f_j)=\mathrm{lk}(\phi(f_i^+),\phi f_i)=-\mathrm{lk}(f_i^+,f_i)=-\mathrm{lk}(f_j^-,f_i).$$

Comment: Sorry, the above should read 
$$\mathrm{lk}((\phi f_i)^-,\phi f_j)=\mathrm{lk}(\phi(f_i^+),\phi f_j) = -\mathrm{lk}(f_i^+,f_j)=-\mathrm{lk}(f_j^-,f_i).$$ 
See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2913476/332390

Comment: @Hrhm Ah, I see, you and my other answer helped me see what this one is saying (and this one is confusing). It is true that the mirror image of the knot has $-V^T$ as its Seifert matrix. This answer is factoring it into two operations for some reason: first taking the mirror image and incidentally reversing the orientation of the knot due to taking the mirror image of the Seifert surface, and second reversing the orientation of the Seifert surface. These correspond to two of your three equalities, if I've got it right this time.