# torus crossing directions & Conway polynomial

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, topological-groups, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I know that the Conway polynomial of a trefoil knot with all negative crossings is 1 + x^2.

I was therefore wondering, would the Conway polynomial of an equivalent trefoil knot with all positive crossings also be 1 + x^2?

Is there a general theorem for converting between the conway polynomials of equivalent knots with all positive or all negative crossings?

Answer (score 0):

For a reference, you might consider looking at chapter 8 of Lickorish's book *An Introduction to Knot Theory*.  In short, the Conway polynomial is from a normalized Alexander polynomial, and the Alexander polynomial is invariant under mirror image.  I think it's Fox's *A Quick Trip Through Knot Theory* that gives a nice reason for this, but this follows from the fact that the Wirtinger presentation can have relations that are either from loops *above* or *below* a crossing, and one can pass between these group presentations by formally replacing each generator with its inverse; since these are group presentations for the same group, this is reflected in the Alexander polynomial by a $t\leftrightarrow t^{-1}$ symmetry.

A definition of the Conway polynomial is that it is $\det(t^{1/2}A-t^{-1/2}A^T)$ with $x=t^{-1/2}-t^{1/2}$, where $A$ is a Seifert matrix for a given link, which for a Seifert surface $S\subset S^3$ is the matrix of a form $H_1(S)\times H_1(S)\to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $([\alpha],[\beta])\mapsto \operatorname{lk}(\alpha,\beta^+)$ when $\alpha,\beta$ are simple closed curves and $\beta^+$ is the curve pushed off $S$ in the positive normal direction with respect to the orientation of the surface.  The corresponding Seifert matrix for the mirror image of everything is $-A^T$, as outlined in this answer: [Seifert Matrix of Amphichiral Knots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913051/seifert-matrix-of-amphichiral-knots/2913476#2913476).

Thus, the Conway polynomial of a mirror image is
\begin{align}
\det(t^{1/2}(-A^T)-t^{-1/2}(-A^T)^T)&=\det(-(t^{1/2}A-t^{-1/2}A^T)^T)\\
&=(-1)^n\det(t^{1/2}A-t^{-1/2}A^T)
\end{align}
where $n=\operatorname{rank}(H_1(S))$, which at least for a knot is even.  Hence, for a knot the Conway polynomial is invariant under mirror images.  (In general, this is true for links with an odd number of components.)

So: the Conway polynomial of a knot and its mirror image are the same.  In particular, the two chiral forms of the trefoil both have $1+x^2$ as their Conway polynomials.

Comment: thank you for your very detailed explanation. Does this also extend to 5 crossing torus knots? In other words, would the Conway polynomial of a torus with 5 positive crossings equal that of a torus with 5 negative crossings, namely 1 + x^2 +x^4?

Comment: @platano19 If the knots you are talking about are mirror images of each other, then yes, they would have the same Conway polynomials.  It is likely easy enough to check by hand using the skein relation (and also be a good exercise).

Comment: great thank you very much!